# wide char string functions on linux / windows

Tags: c, linux, windows, string, unicode

I want to create a string library with two different string classes for handling UTF-8 and UCS-2 (which I beleive is some kind of UTF-16 not handling surrogates and characters above 0xFFFF).

On windows platforms, wide chars are 2 octets wide. On Linux they are 4. So what happens with functions related to wide char strings ? Do you pass buffers of 2 octets wide items on windows and 4 octets wide items on linux ? If yes then it makes these functions totally different on windows and linux, which doesn't make them really "standard"...

How can one handle this problem when trying to create a library that is supposed to manipulate wide chars the same way for cross platform code ? Thank you.

Comment: glib has string utility functions that work on UTF-8, which may be helpful.

Comment: i assume i could using the narrow char string functions on both linux and windows since they both use one byte chars. My problem is about using wide chars.

Comment: You are proposing to re-invent the wheel.  There are a variety of existing libraries for this kind of thing, with various levels of functionality.  One of the better is the IBM-sponsored, open-source, multi-platform [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) project.

Answer (score 0):

You're right about the different sizes of `wchar_t` on Windows and Linux. That also means you're right about the wide-character handling functions not being too useful. You should probably check out an encoding conversion library such as [libiconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/). Then you can work with UTF-8 internally and just convert on I/O.

Comment: Thanks, but i would like to use an encoding that allows direct access to the N-th character like UCS-2 for performance reasons, this is why i'm looking for a way to use wide chars the same way on windows linux. Maybe i could wrap windows wide string functions to convert from UTF-32 to UCS-2 et reverse, or do the opposite with linux functions.

Comment: Well, you can use iconv to convert to UCS-2, too.

Comment: @Virus721, then I hope you're normalizing the string to use composed characters, e.g. replace "e\u0300" with "è".